# Camera listener service?

Tags: android, camera, actionlistener

I am looking for a way to run a service process in the background of a device, that listens for camera actions. Is this possible?  I have been reading a lot of forums that are around launching the native camera from within an activity, and I can already do this.  What I am after more specifically is the following:

You install the app onto your device.   The app installs a listener service. The service listens for the user to take a picture with the native camera app, and when this happens, the listener service can run code triggered by this action (ie, to send the picture taken to a remote server).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this be done?

Not really.

First, there is no singular "native camera app". There are ~1.5 billion Android devices, spanning thousands of models. These will come with hundreds of different "native camera app" implementations. Plus, users can install other camera apps and use those.

None of them necessarily have to store photos anywhere that you can reach them.

You are certainly welcome to implement a `FileObserver`, looking for photos being stored in some likely locations. However, this will only work while your process is running.